# Trouble with EntityManager Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

For some reason I don't get results when running this from method.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Object[] getPointRaiting(Long id) {
    EntityManager em = createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Query allPointsQuery = em
            .createQuery("Select AVG(r.RATING) from Ratings r WHERE r.POINT_ID = :point");
    allPointsQuery.setParameter("point", id);
    Object[] rating = (Object[]) allPointsQuery.getSingleResult();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    closeEntityManager();
    return rating;
}
```

SQL should be correct as it executes in HSQL db manager and returns the correct value. But java function stops running at query. It does'nt throw any errors just stops. I'm out of ideas, where should I look? (Other similiar methods with count and select all work correctly).

Using HSQLDB and Hibernate.

Found that the following error was thrown:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: RATING of: kaart.entities.Ratings [Select AVG(r.RATING) from kaart.entities.Ratings r WHERE r.POINT_ID = :point]
```

But this does not solve it for me as the RATING property is defined in table and in entity...

```
@Entity @Table(name = "RATINGS") 
public class Ratings implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Point point;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "RATING")
    private int rating;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Ratings() {
        super();
    }

    public Ratings(Point point, User user, int rating) {
        this.point = point;
        this.user = user;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    /*all getters and setters here*/}


@Entity
@Table(name = "POINT")
public class Point implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "point")
    private List<Category> pointsByCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "point")
    private List<Ratings> pointRatings;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "LOCATION")
    private String location;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "LINK")
    private String link;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Point() {
        super();
    }

    public Point(String name, String location, String description, String link, User user) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.description = description;
        this.link = link;
        this.user = user;
    } /* getters and setters*/
```

Comment: First of all you dont need a transaction begin-close for select query. And why are there two entitymanager close?em.close();
    closeEntityManager();

Comment: Entity manager manages entities on multitire architectures, cannot reproduce it just now.

Comment: CloseEntityManager () - closes the EntityManagerFactory what is in the parent class.
After going through debug I finally found that exception is thrown but it's not displayed in the console (edited post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this problem is caused by caps-locked property names: `RATING`, `POINT_ID`.

Try replacing them with the ones that you use in `Ratings` class, probably:

```
Select AVG(r.rating) from Ratings r WHERE r.point.id = :point_id
```

Comment: Unforunately CriteriaBuilder solution does not work also (I got the avg but where clause did'nt work properly). 

Problem is that pointId is not defined in Ratings class, it's a foreign key (sorry that I forgot to mention that...). Ratings class has rating (int) point(Point class) and Ratings table has ID, RATING, POINT_ID(FK) fields.

Comment: @Noripsni Can you please post `Ratings` and `Point` classes?

Comment: @Noripsni Try the query in my answer.

Comment: It works, such a simple solution that I feel like I should have came to it, but you live to learn :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass JP-QL inside em.createQuery(). 
But seems you are using native SQL with values like r.RATING, r.POINT_ID, which may not be in the Java entity. Replace it with equivalent java entity variable, could be pointId

```
em.createQuery("Select AVG(r.RATING) from Ratings r WHERE r.POINT_ID = :point");
```

If you want to use native sql, you can use em.createNativeQuery().

Comment: You forgot to fix the query, it is still using DB fields.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev Thanks, I did n't fixed it 'coz we don't know his correct fields.